# OpenAL воспроизводит лишнее

Tags: mp3, c++

Разбираю пример отсюда http://steps3d.narod.ru/tutorials/openal-tutorial.html

При воспроизведении mp3 и ogg фалов по очереди (alSourceQueueBuffers) когда делаешь stop и после play, то при вызове play воспроизводит конец последнего воспроизведенного буфера.

Пробовал чистить буферы, чистить source, но ошибка осталась.

Если воспроизводить буфер целиком (без alSourceQueueBuffers), то такой ошибки не наблюдается.

Во время Stop происходит:
 alSourceStop(_source);
 alSourceUnqueueBuffers(_source, 2, _buffers);

Всего гружу все время по два буффера размером 1000000 байт.

Предполагаю, что это глюк OpenAL, может переинициализация девайса поможет..

Подскажите кто что думает по этому поводу, наблюдается ли у вас такой глюк?

Answer (score 1):

помогло переоткрытие файла